# Selecting rows where remainder (modulo) is 1 after division by 2?

Tags: sql, database, select, where-clause, modulus

There is a column in options that hold an integer. I want to select the row only if that value % 2 = 1.

I know this can be done in 2 queries but is it possible to do it in 1?

Answer (score 88):

MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, SQLite support using the percent sign as the modulus:

```
WHERE column % 2 = 1
```

For Oracle, you have to use the [MOD function](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/mod.php):

```
WHERE MOD(column, 2) = 1
```

Answer (score 20):

At least some versions of SQL (Oracle, Informix, DB2, ISO Standard) support:

```
WHERE MOD(value, 2) = 1
```

MySQL supports '%' as the modulus operator:

```
WHERE value % 2 = 1
```

Comment: MOD() for SQL Anywhere; % for Sybase ASE.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** *Disregard this answer, as I must have misunderstood the question.*

```
select *
  from Table
  where len(ColName) mod 2 = 1
```

The exact syntax depends on what flavor of SQL you're using.

Comment: len? The OP didn't mentions a string or varchar

Answer (score 1):

`select * from table where value % 2 = 1` works fine in mysql.