# Select Rows with id having even number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I am passing a simple query where I am searching for specific rows where `OrderID` is an even number

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE mod(OrderID,2) = 0;
```

Error :

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'mod(OrderID,2) = 0'.

Comment: Oracle-Server or SQL-Server ?? @solankikaushik

Comment: Doesn't look like T-SQL (MS SQL Server) to me - there's no `mod` function that I've heard of. OP could do `SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderID % 2 = 0` though, I think.

Comment: @Malik Asif : Sql Server

Comment: Go to link: [Already given answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756928/select-row-if-the-value-2-1-mod) OR Query is: SELECT * FROM Orders where OrderId % 2 = 0;

Comment: @Tim : How to perform this query in ms-sql server ?

Comment: works for me in sql plus server

Comment: This will work in MySQL

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You are not using Oracle, so you should be using the modulus operator:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders where OrderID % 2 = 0;
```

The `MOD()` function exists in Oracle, which is the source of your confusion.

Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756928/select-row-if-the-value-2-1-mod) which discusses your problem.

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT * FROM Orders where OrderID % 2 = 0;///this is for even numbers

SELECT * FROM Orders where OrderID % 2 != 0;///this is for odd numbers
```

Answer (score 8):

Sql Server we can use %

```
select * from orders where ID % 2 = 0;
```

This can be used in both Mysql and oracle.
It is more affection to use mod function that %.

```
select * from orders where mod(ID,2) = 0
```

Comment: The question is about SQL Server, not Oracle or MySQL though.

Answer (score 6):

MOD() function exists in both **Oracle and MySQL**, but not in SQL Server.

In SQL Server, try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM Orders where OrderID % 2 = 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

--This is for oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Station WHERE MOD(Id,2) = 0 ORDER BY City;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM STATION WHERE ID%2=0 ORDER BY CITY;
```

Answer (score 2):

**For SQL Server:**

`SELECT * FROM Orders where OrderID % 2 = 0;`  //this is for even numbers

`SELECT * FROM Orders where OrderID % 2 != 0;` //this is for odd numbers

**For Oracle and MySQL, you have to use the MOD function:**

`select * from orders where mod(ID,2) = 0`

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, all these options can be used for `MOD`:

`SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE MOD(ID,2) = 0 ORDER BY CITY;`

OR

`SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE ID % 2 = 0 ORDER BY CITY;`

OR

`SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE ID MOD 2 = 0 ORDER BY CITY;`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
;With MYCTE(Empid)
As 
(
  SELECT * FROM employeeodd 
)
Select *
From MYCTE
where empid % 2 = 0;

;With MYCTE(Empid)
As 
(
  SELECT * FROM employeeodd 
)
Select *
From MYCTE
where empid % 2! = 0;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, Row_Number() 
OVER(ORDER BY country_gid) AS sdfg  FROM eka_mst_tcountry ) t 
WHERE t.country_gid % 2 = 0
```